# Should I build Fact & Dim tables or use Views over highly normalised ODS?

Tags: ssas, cube

We are designing a high-level data architecture with an ESB transporting data from source's & being consumed by our data warehouse, stored in the ODS. The ESB connectors will translate source data to conform to a highly normalised standard data model(i.e. IEC 61968-11:2013), the ODS will also be structured based on the standard. We will then be using this to present to users via data marts & OLAP Cubes (SSAS). However I am unsure if, with a highly normalised ODS, best practice would be to use views against the ODS for the data marts & fact/dim sources for the cubes OR if fact/dim tables should be generated for the cubes and data mart views.

I have been searching for recommendations / best practices and have found a general pattern to use views to separate cube's from fact/dim tables but not if views against the ODS tables can be used instead of fact/dim tables.

All data (once received from the ESB) will be held and cube processing will be carried out on the same physical host. We are looking for the best balance between storage required & performance.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Views are generally slower than real tables.  If you have the luxury of an etl process to build a staging environment to feed your cube, I would say construct real fact and dim tables.  If your data volumes are not huge, views may suffice but will not be as performant.

Comment: Thanks, so would the ideal be "Source -> ODS -> Fact & Dim tables -> Cube" ?

Comment: Yes, (not sure what ODS stands for)